# Error: Symbol already different kind: <function name> in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

**What i am trying to do?**

I am trying to implement a **`FAR`** call in TASM 8086 assembler.

**What is the problem?**

I get the following error when I run my code:

***Error publicDr.asm(27) Symbol already different kind: DIS***

**mycode:**

```
data segment    
            msg db 10,13,'First Code Segment.$'
            msg2 db 10,13,'Second Code Segment.$'                    
data ends                                              
        public dis                    
code1 segment            
            assume cs:code1                                                            
            dis proc far
               mov ah, 09h
               mov dx, offset msg
               int 21h
               ret                  
            dis endp                                       
code1 ends         
        extrn dis:far      ; getting error here               
code2 segment
               assume cs:code2, ds:data
main:                
               mov ax, data
               mov ds, ax

               mov ah, 09h
               mov dx, offset msg2
               int 21h                                 

               call dis                   
               mov ah, 04ch
               int 21h
code2 ends                                     
end main
```

so what is this error and how would i fix the above code to make it work ?

Comment: What is your question? Also, what is the function name in the error message?

Comment: `extrn dis:far` says there is a label in another module, but you have defined it in the current file. Just remove ``extrn dis:far``

Comment: @fuz Edited the question have a look and the name of the function is `DIS` you can see it in the error message that i posted.

Comment: @MichaelPetch okay should i have to create another asm file and define `DIS` function in it ?

Comment: You don't have to put it in another file. `extern` is only needed when it is external.If you put `dis proc far` then you'll need to use `extrn dis:far`. But you should be able to get the desired effect you want in the same file. The `call dis` should end up being a far call.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I guess you have a typo there its `extrn` not `extern`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I thought i would learn `FAR` call as well as `public` and `extrn` directives in this one example but it seems i am only able to learn the implementation of `FAR` call. can you please produce an example that would do the `FAR` call using `public` and `extrn` directives ? It would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want that place dis proc far into a separate asm file. You then assemble both files separately and link them together.

Comment: @MichaelPetch okay now i created the two files and assembled them now how would i link them ? should I use `include` directive for that ?

Comment: linking process is being handled by linker. If you assemble with TASM, then you are probably using TLINK for linking. `Include` is assemble-time directive, not related to linking, so "no". Produce two different object files (`.obj`), one obj file has public symbol `DIS` (and code of the procedure defining that symbol), other obj file says it needs external `DIS` from outside and will use that value for far `call`. Linker will connect them and set the correct value to `call`.

Comment: @Ped7g I am using GUI TURBO ASSEMBLER not the dos version so i don't know how to linking in it ?

Comment: I have no idea, never met with that software. Depends how it handles projects with several source files, whether it creates some Makefile, or some batch file, and what compiler and linker it does use. I guess the "GUI TURBO ASSEMBLER" is some half-piracy attempt to leverage original Borland's TASM functionality under some text editor with IDE features (so internally it somehow must call the command line tools). Will try to google it, what it is, meanwhile check some options, if you can switch on some "verbose" mode for compilation, to see actual command line commands used.

Comment: As expected, it's some custom IDE packed together with TASM/TLINK from Borland. As far as I know, that SW was never released into public domain, it's still commercially blocked by current owner of Borland (can't recall the company name right now), so this is sort of piracy, but IIRC buying original TASM right now is next to impossible, so I personally don't mind anyone using it for personal education... It's still a bit sad people resort to using non-available tools, when there's whole world of OSS alternatives, like NASM (but missing a well designed ASM IDE? Or I just didn't find one yet).

Comment: @Ped7g Okay leave it then can you tell me which assembler is best ? thanks anyways. :)

Comment: But .. anyway.. that means, that you *can* use TASM/TLINK from command line on your own... you can create a DOS batch file (.BAT) calling tasm for each .asm file, and final tlink to create exe. You will just lose the build process directly from IDE. If the IDE has nice debugger, you will maybe have to put extra effort to make that work with your externally build exe too. All the needed tools are inside your package already.

Comment: About best assembler: TASM is (or rather WAS) actually very good, also MASM from microsoft (freely available with certain MS SDK downloads, at least 32b version, 16b maybe not), but if you want free software (like free in liberty, not free as free beer), you can pick any either NASM-syntax (similar to TASM, but different!) family (NASM or YASM), or FASM (quite specialized with it's own way of doing things, it's whole assembler written in assembly, fascinating... syntax is near NASM). All of these are open source, and actively maintained, so they support also new x86 instructions and 64b mode.

Comment: I'm personally using linux as OS (KDE neon), NASM (ordinary version from distribution repository) for compilation, dosbox 0.74 for DOS emulation, and `edb-debugger` (built from sources from github) for linux debugging. I edit sources in Kate (KDE text editor). For DOS debugging I somehow unearthed my old commercial copy of TASM, so I have also tasm+tlink+*turbo debugger* under dosbox. YMMV. But I create minimal amount of assembly work, only for fun, mostly just helping people on SO, no big projects.